# why doesn't the c# update query for storedprocedure work?

Tags: asp.net, stored-procedures

This question arises out of a net article to insert and update a row of a GridView in a popup window. [here](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Add-Edit-Update-Records-in-GridView-using-Modal-Popup-in-ASP.Net.aspx).

Clicking on the edit button in GridView, you get a popup window for edit. You edit the window and click 'save' to save it in database.  the save method is :

```
protected void Save(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    
    
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())

    {
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        //cmd.CommandText = "AddUpdateCustomer";

        cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE [Customers] SET [CompanyName] = @CompanyName ,[ContactName] = @ContactName WHERE CustomerID = @CustomerID";


        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerID", txtCustomerID.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ContactName", txtContactName.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CompanyName", txtCompany.Text);
        
        GridView1.DataSource =  this.GetData(cmd);
        GridView1.DataBind();

        

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        
    }
}
```

The online article used the commented line for `cmd.CommandText` which I changed as that did not work nor did I find its utility. I also added the last line          `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` to execute the query But actually no change in DB.

What might be wrong with the `Save` method and how to deal with that wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've requested a call to a stored procedure, but the line you commented-out is the one that contains the stored procedure name.

It looks like you're actually executing raw SQL so you should try instead:

```
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
```

But your CommandText line won't work either because it isn't real SQL. It needs to include the content of the variables rather than the variable names. And also you should be executing a query rather than a non-query.

```
protected void Save(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
    {
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.CommandText = String.Concat("UPDATE [Customers] SET [CompanyName] = ", txtCompany.Text, ", [ContactName] = ", txtContactName.Text, " WHERE CustomerID = ", txtCustomerId.Text, ";");

etc
```

Comment: I had to comment the line out as that did not work. If i want to keep that, is anything missing in the code then  ?

Comment: Please see my revised answer. You need to create valid SQL in your CommandText.

Comment: that worked, but the problem is I have to refresh the page to get the updated data in the GridView. Can you please tell how to get it updated at the same time ? using `autopostback` or any other elegant way ?

Comment: Try the SQL code I've added to see if that works. And please note the serious SQL injection risk when using unfiltered text input.

Comment: ok, but asked how to use the `storedprocedure` and update the GridView data simultaneously .

Comment: Is this.GetData actually getting the data, ie executing the SQL query and returning a dataset or datatable?

Comment: the `private DataTable GetData(SqlCommand cmd)` method is there in the online article mentioned in my post.

Comment: So didn't the article I mentioned in my post (http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Add-Edit-Update-Records-in-GridView-using-Modal-Popup-in-ASP.Net.aspx) implement it correctly ? let me test your code ..

Comment: Error 2 The name 'txtCustomerId' does not exist in the current context C:\BegASPNET\popup\CSharp.aspx.cs 111 168 C:\BegASPNET\popup\ - This is the error message I get.

Comment: that should be `txtCustomerID.Text` instead of `txtCustomerId.Text`. But no no change in DB let alone dynamically showing the edited value in the GridView.

Comment: As a beginner I could not understand that I had to create a stored procedure first before it could work. It works now.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write your code for filling Textbox's at page load as below :

```
public page_load()
{
   if(!ispostBack)
   {
     // Write code to fill controls first time
    }
}
```

this is because on every postback asp.net will save the controls value in viewstate and when page return from server controlls are filled with old value and database table will update with old value rather than new value